I get error, "Error: Expression expected" when I run my test in my Vite application
My test fails for some weird reason.
Below is the file that contains the whole code, I am not sure why it fails, even when I used different matchers and attributes that I expect to work like "getByPlaceholderText", it stills fail with the same error.
sum.test.js
/* eslint-disable no-undef */
import React from 'react';
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';

function InputComponent() {
    return <input type="text" name="userName" />;
}

test('renders input with aria-label', () => {
    render(<InputComponent />);
    const inputElement = screen.getByRole('textbox');
    expect(inputElement).toBeInTheDocument();
});


The error in the console says,
 FAIL  sum.test.js [ sum.test.js ]
Error: Expression expected
 ❯ getRollupError ../../../.nvm/versions/node/v20.5.0/lib/node_modules/vitest/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/parseAst.js:396:41

 Test Files  1 failed (1)
      Tests  no tests
   Start at  15:08:31
   Duration  0ms


You did not put the filename of the component being tested. Is it sum.js or sum.jsx? If you are using .jsx extention on the component, then the test must also have that same extension, so sum.test.jsx. If not, then a similar error to what you wrote will be thrown by vitest.
